# HTML select a folder and a non existing file name

Tags: html, file, input, directory

After getting a datasream from a server I would like to select an existing folder and set a new file name to which the stream should be stored.
The  of HTML expects an existing file name to be entered.
What is the way to do it ? (html and jscript)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of HTML not letting you select un-made files but if you want to deal with files have a look at this [MDN reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files)

The file does not need to be made for your website to target it!